# Powershell Gui Multiline TextBox to retain original cursor position after key press

Tags: powershell, winforms, user-interface, textbox, position

I'm working on a small gui project, sending messages to Teams channel via Powershell.
I created the Gui with text box, and enabled function activation on button press.
I would like the cursor to remain at the begining of the box i.e. 0 place on first line. Haven't been able to find any solution to that. Code below. Please advise.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Function ButtonClick
{
    $test = $textBoxDisplay.Text
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType 'Application/Json' -Body "{`"text`":`"$test`"}" -Uri $myTeamsWebhook
    $textBoxDisplay.Clear()
    
}

$myTeamsWebhook = 'xxx'


[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$button = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$button.Location = '10, 10'
$button.Name = "buttonGo"
$button.Size = '75, 25'
$button.TabIndex = 0
$button.Text = "&Go"
$button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
$button.Add_Click({ButtonClick})

$textBoxDisplay = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
$textBoxDisplay.Location = '12, 50'
$textBoxDisplay.Multiline = $true
$textBoxDisplay.Name = "textBoxDisplay"
$textBoxDisplay.Size = '470, 150'
$textBoxDisplay.TabIndex = 1
$textBoxDisplay.Focus()
$textBoxDisplay.AcceptsReturn = $false
$textBoxDisplay.WordWrap = $true

$textBoxDisplay.add_KeyDown({
if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter"){ButtonClick}

})


$mainForm = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$mainForm.Size = '500, 250'
$mainForm.Controls.Add($button)
$mainForm.Controls.Add($textBoxDisplay)
$mainForm.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedDialog
$mainForm.Name = "mainForm"
$mainForm.Text = "GUI Test"

$mainForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` properties to 0? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-select-text-in-the-windows-forms-textbox-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Yes I tried, It did not work. Cursor still goes to second line.

Comment: Why do you do `$textBoxDisplay.add_KeyDown()` ? If this is a multiline box, the user is bound to use the Enter key to continue on the next line. Take that away and I would add `$textBoxDisplay.Focus()` as final line in your ButtonClick function. Otherwise, do `$textBoxDisplay.Add_KeyUp` instead of KeyDown, so the enter is written before you clear the box